# changing the sub-string delimiter in a regex, does not return same result

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I have a problem with understanding a regex.

I have the following string:

> aaa'dd?'d'xxx'

In this string, the

> '

is substring delimiter and

> ?

is a escape character for the

> '

.

In Oracle SQL, I have a sentence which splits my string in substrings, based on substring delimiter:

```
select replace(

  regexp_substr(q'[aaa'dd?'d'xxx']', '(.*?[^?])(''|$)', 1, level, null, 1),

   '?''',

   '''') as result

FROM dual

connect by level <= regexp_count(q'[aaa'dd?'d'xxx']', '(.*?[^?])(''|$)');
```

In this case, the result is:

> aaa
>
> dd'd
>
> xxx

... which is correct.

My problem comes from the fact that I want to change the sub-string delimiter from

> '

into

> +

.

In this case, the main string becomes

> aaa+dd?+d+xxx+

I modified the SQL statement in:

```
SELECT REPLACE(

  regexp_substr(q'[aaa+dd?+d+xxx+]', '(.*?[^?])(+|$)', 1, level, null, 1),

   '?''',

   '''') as result

FROM dual

connect by level <= regexp_count(q'[aaa+dd?+d+xxx+]', '(.*?[^?])(+|$)');
```

... and the result is different:

> a
>
> a
>
> a
>
> +
>
> d
>
> d
>
> ?+
>
> d
>
> +
>
> x
>
> x
>
> x
>
> +

Can you point me what am I doing wrong in my modified script in order to get same result, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regexp `+` means 1 or more of the preceding pattern.  Try escaping the `+` with `\` making your regexp `'(.*?[^?])(\+|$)'`